# Swift using Dismiss alert message

Tags: swift, swift2

I want to dismiss alert message when tap out side the `alertController` in swift language.
[image]

Thank's advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the tap gesture in your view in the `viewDidLoad` like this way

```
let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.viewTapped(_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Now add this `viewTapped` in your `ViewController`

```
func viewTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi Nirav,  i need to touch out off promptcode mesage box only then screen goto add money page.